# Integral solution to a simple equation

Tags: number-theory

consider the following equation:
$r^4 + 100 s^4 = q^2$
It has one positive integer solution $(r,s,q) = (6,4,164)$.
Is there any general solution (positive integer solution) to it, similar to the generating formula for Pythagoreas tuples?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Write it as $(r^2)^2 + (10s^2)^2 = q^2$ and you can observe that $r^2$ and $10s^2$ and $q$ must form a pythagorean triple.